# Using a function constructor for evaluating AJAX result instead of eval()

Tags: javascript, ajax, function

Can anyone suggest a reason why this may be better or worse than using eval() for AJAX calls? I think I found on a Google related page that advocated it over eval() since eval runs in the global scope whereas the functions contents here don't.

```
str = '{a: 90, b: 99}';
callback = new Function ('return ' + str);
obj = callback();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is effectively `eval` with messier syntax. It has all the drawbacks of `eval`.

The function body will still have access to the global scope. It is still slow. Bad data will throw exceptions. Untrusted data can utilise XSS.